# What could lead to JPA entity state discrepancy within single thread?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am experiencing a strange intermittent issue with JPA/Hibernate and MySQL 5.7. I'm looking for suggestions.

My entity is defined with:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false)
protected Date createdAt;
```

which translates to the following SQL table definition:

```
`created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL
```

and the timestamp is set upon entity creation using

```
@PrePersist
protected void onCreate() {
    updatedAt = createdAt = new Date();
}
```

JPA save operation sometimes leads to SQL error due to null value being *supposedly* sent in UPDATE query via Spring CRUD rest repository.

I have verified the post request includes the `created_at` field, but more importantly, the following screenshot of my log feed confirms that the `created_at` value **is** present. However subsequent save blows out. (There is only one "createdAt" field if anyone wondered):
[image: screenshot]

*Note: The AOP advices are used for spring-acl integration and don't manipulate entity data (they do provide a convenient interception for logging purposes as seen in the screenshot above).*

I can't reliably replicate the error. What could be the reason behind this strange behaviour? I thought second level caching - tried disabling `@Cacheable` on the entity, but to no avail. Enabling detailed logging with SQL binding is not practical due to irregular nature of the issue.

Comment: there are annotations CreationTimestamp and UpdateTimestamp (in HIBERNATE) for field like create_at and update_at. Is it possible to use this annotation instead of AOP?

Comment: @Orthodox I updated my question with detail on how I'm setting the timestamp - I'm not using AOP for that; AOP only logs the values. The point is - the entity already has the value set on the way in (in HTTP POST); confirmed via log entry in AOP class.

Comment: Looks like 2 instances.

Comment: Are you doing merge somewhere?

Comment: Error during managed flush! If fou make flush, then PreUpdate invoked. What code in preUpdate? And what about using CreationTimestamp and UpdateTimestamp instead of PreXXXXX?

Comment: @Antoniossss it's a vanilla HTTP PUT (= update) via spring-data-rest. No explicit merging occurs. The created_at is already set in the request and `@PrePersist` doesn't get involved since it is an update.